# The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.- BCS

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, bcs, external-content-type, odata

We are trying to Consume OData in BCS using an App External Content Type. The OData service that we used is http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc

We followed [this](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sharepoint-2013-business-connectivity-services-consuming-odata-in-bcs-using-an-app-external-content-type) to create app external content type.

But when we are trying to access the list we are getting below error:

```
"The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required."
```

Does anyone have any idea what we are missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I often get this message and find I can solve the issue temporarily by going to my internet explorer Settings via the menu options -

Tools / Internet Options / Connections / LAN Settings / deselect the Automatically Detect Settings option box and click okay.

My system auto reverts my change every so often thus requiring me to redo the option change.

No Idea why this is I just worked it out twiddling manically :) Hope it has some use to you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and will try that also. I also found out that this issue is due to our environment. I deployed my App to O365 and it worked :)